# Prevent Backbone collection reset event on success callback of fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I call fetch and bass success callback to it. Is it possible to prevent collection reset event in this callback?

Comment: I think the default already is not to raise the reset event unless you pass `reset: true` http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Answer (score 0):

Reset is not called on fetch unless you specify it in the options

`MyCollection.fetch({reset:true})` will reset your collection but otherwise it won't so I'm not sure what's your problem here.
`MyCollection.fetch({reset:false})` is not even documented because reset is not triggered after a fetch. Simple fetch will merge your new results with existing models.

> When the model data returns from the server, it uses set to
>   (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass {reset:
>   true}, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) reset.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Hope it helps.